# Python removing lines that contain more then one tilde

Tags: python, tilde

I'm kind've stuck on this problem! I have a massive text file (3 million lines or so) and I need to remove any lines that contain more then one tilde. Could someone be as kind to help me out! Please and thank you .

Here is what I have so far:

```
import re 

f_in = 'C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\Python\\Pagelinks\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned2.txt'

f_out = 'C:\\Users\\John\\Documents\\Python\\Pagelinks\\pagelinkSample_10K_cleaned3.txt'

with open(f_in, 'r') as fin: 

        with open(f_out, 'w') as fout: 

              for line in fin:
```

stuck here, i'm thinking if line count for tilde contains more then one delete line?

Thanks!

Comment: Why use python when `grep -v '~~'` does the job?

Answer (score 3):

```
for line in fin:
    if line.count('~') < 2:
        fout.write(line)
```

Comment: Suggestion: `if line.count('~') < 2:`, and remove the `continue`.